# IUnitOfWork to DomainService constructor using Unity container

Tags: c#, silverlight, unity-container, data-access-layer, ria

I created Silverlight application and I want to realise it via WCF RIA Services. There are 3 projects in my solution:

1. Data access layer library which contains all db logic and entities. I will use *IUnitOfWork* interface to communicate with it:

   ```
   public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
   {
        IRepository<Customer> Customers { get; }
        IRepository<Product> Products { get; }
        IRepository<Order> Orders { get; }
        void Save();
   }
   ```
2. WCF RIA Services project where I created custom *DomainService* class. Its constructor takes *IUnitOfWork* interface parameter:

   ```
   [EnableClientAccess()]
   public void StoreService : DomainService
   {
        private IUnitOfWork _repository;
        public StoreService(IUnitOfWork repository)
        {
             _repository = repository;
        }
        // ... some methods to query _repository
   }
   ```
3. Client project (its written in WPF).

So, I want to use Unity IoC container to path interface implementation into service. I can't understand where need to create custom service factory or something like that and where to register it to be used by system. For example, I know that in ASP.NET MVC there is *DefaultControllerFactory* class which I need to derive. Then put my IoC bindings in it and then register it in Global.asax.cs file. Can you help me, please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DomainService` exposes a static property called `DomainService.DomainServiceFactory`.

You'll need a custom class that implements `IDomainServiceFactory`

```
interface IDomainServiceFactory
{
  DomainService CreateDomainService(Type domainServiceType, DomainServiceContext context);
  void ReleaseDomainService(DomainService domainService)
}
```

I've copied and pasted a blog post from Fredrik Normen [how to wire up Unity to DomainService](http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/wcf-ria-services-unity-domainservicefactory).

```
public class MyDomainServiceFactory : IDomainServiceFactory
{

    public DomainService CreateDomainService(Type domainServiceType, DomainServiceContext context)
    {
        var service = Global.UnityContainer.Resolve(domainServiceType) as DomainService;
        service.Initialize(context);

        return service;
    }


    public void ReleaseDomainService(DomainService domainService)
    {
        domainService.Dispose();
    }
}
```

In your `Global.asax`

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DomainService.Factory = new MyDomainServiceFactory();

   UnityContainer.RegisterType<StoreService>();
   UnityContainer.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWorkImpl>();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's really what I needed. I implement such solution myself earlier)